# After integrating OneSignal Cordova SDK my App delegate methods are not called for UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate

Tags: ios, cordova, onesignal

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import <UserNotifications/UserNotifications.h>
#import "MainViewController.h"

@interface AppDelegate () <UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate>

@end

@implementation AppDelegate


- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication*)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary*)launchOptions
{
    self.viewController = [[MainViewController alloc] init];
    [self registerForNotification];
    return [super application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
}

- (void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center willPresentNotification:(UNNotification*)notification withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UNNotificationPresentationOptions options))completionHandler {
  // This method are not getting called
completionHandler(UNNotificationPresentationOptionAlert|UNNotificationPresentationOptionBadge|UNNotificationPresentationOptionSound);
}

- (void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center didReceiveNotificationResponse:(nonnull UNNotificationResponse* )response withCompletionHandler:(nonnull void (^)(void))completionHandler {
   // This method are not getting called
    NSDictionary *userInfo =  response.notification.request.content.userInfo;
    completionHandler();
}


- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken
{
    NSLog(@"DEVICE_TOKEN :: %@", deviceToken);

    const unsigned *tokenBytes = [deviceToken bytes];
    NSString *hexToken = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%08x%08x%08x%08x%08x%08x%08x%08x",
                          ntohl(tokenBytes[0]), ntohl(tokenBytes[1]), ntohl(tokenBytes[2]),
                          ntohl(tokenBytes[3]), ntohl(tokenBytes[4]), ntohl(tokenBytes[5]),
                          ntohl(tokenBytes[6]), ntohl(tokenBytes[7])];

    NSString *apnDeviceToken = hexToken;
    NSLog(@"APN_DEVICE_TOKEN :: %@", apnDeviceToken);
}


-(void)registerForNotification
{
    if(@available(iOS 10.0, *))
    {
        UNUserNotificationCenter *center = [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter];
        center.delegate = self;
        [center requestAuthorizationWithOptions:(UNAuthorizationOptionSound | UNAuthorizationOptionAlert | UNAuthorizationOptionBadge) completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError * _Nullable error)
         {
             if(!error)
             {
                 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^ {
                     [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];  // required to get the app to do anything at all about push notifications
                     NSLog(@"Push registration success." );
                 });
             }
             else
             {
                 NSLog(@"Push registration FAILED" );
                 NSLog(@"ERROR: %@ - %@", error.localizedFailureReason, error.localizedDescription );
                 NSLog(@"SUGGESTIONS: %@ - %@", error.localizedRecoveryOptions, error.localizedRecoverySuggestion );
             }
         }];
    }

}

@end
```

The `didReceiveNotificationResponse` and `willPresentNotification` did not trigger. I'm not able to handle Other APNS notification which is not related to one signal Cordova plugin  SDK notification.

Is there any way that my app delegate methods for UserNotifications delegate methods will trigger in Cordova ios when one signal plugin used?

I suspect that due to swizzling the app delegate methods by one signal callbacks are not triggered in the original Appdelegate file.

Please help on this if we have any other way to get my app delegate 
 UserNotifications delegate methods trigger.

As one signal uses the static frameworks in Cordova there is no way to change the code inside the plugin.

This is the one signal plugin for Cordova github https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-Cordova-SDK

Comment: Tried with there latest version of SDK seems to work fine now